# "invalid csrf token" error if adding httpOnly: true

Tags: node.js, csrf-token

I am getting invalid csrf token error with code EBADCSRFTOKEN if I am passing httpOnly:true option.

If I am removing httpOnly: true from the res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken(), {sameSite: true, secure: true, httpOnly: true}); then it is working without any error.

But due to security concern I need to pass httpOnly: true.
Can anyone help in getting what is the issue here?

Below is the example of my code.

```
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(csurf({cookie: {secure: true, sameSite: true, httpOnly: true}}));

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.code !== 'EBADCSRFTOKEN')
        return next(err);
    else
        console.log("Error:", err.message?err.message:err);

    // handle CSRF token errors here
    res.status(403).json({'errorMessage':'Not Authorized'});
})

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken(), {sameSite: true, secure: true, httpOnly: true});
    res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','SAMEORIGIN');
    res.setHeader('Cache-control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0');
    res.setHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    next();
});
```